# Unicode JTextArea displays bad from jar; fine in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, unicode, jar

When I run my program from netbeans the Unicode looks fine. But when I run it from a compiled jar, it does not display correctly.

The following attempt did not fix it

```
Font font = new Font("Arial Unicode MS", Font.PLAIN, 16);
textarea.setFont(font);
// the two lines above were my attempt to fix the display, no luck
textarea.read( new FileReader( file.getAbsolutePath() ), null );
```

Here is the input text:

この文の長さは、Twitterの中で許容されるべきである。この文は長すぎない。この文はならず長すぎます。

Here is the result when I load that string from the program launched from the jar version:

Ð”Ð»Ð¸Ð½Ð° Ñ�Ñ‚Ð¾Ð³Ð¾ Ð¿Ñ€ÐµÐ´Ð»Ð¾Ð¶ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ñ� Ð´Ð¾Ð»Ð¶Ð½Ñ‹ Ð±Ñ‹Ñ‚ÑŒ Ð¿Ñ€Ð¸ÐµÐ¼Ð»ÐµÐ¼Ñ‹ Ð² Twitter.

Comment: are you running with the same jre in netbeans and from outside??

Comment: Yes, I think.rom (1) from command line: C:\Users\bryans>java -version
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode) - and (2) from about netbeans: Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.0 (Build 201403101706)
Java: 1.8.0_05; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.5-b02
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_05-b13
System: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_US (nb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but you should try with another `Reader` to specify another charset.

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");  
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), charset));
textarea.read( reader , null );
```

Comment: One slight change and it worked beautifully. Had to set it to "UTF-8" - not "UTF-16" When I set it to "UTF-16" it just gave me one long string with Chinese characters. Many thanks to you!

Comment: I will accept the answer with the green mark for sure! But before I close this very fruitful thread, I have one more follow on. My program also writes results to a second textarea called "resulttextarea" and I cannot find the way to apply your great answer to it to get it to show proper UTF-8.

    'StreamResult result = new StreamResult (result2);'
    'String filetext = new Scanner(result2).useDelimiter("\\A").next();'resulttextarea.setText(filetext);

Comment: @JediGrunge You could open another thread asking a new question there is nothing bad with that, you could use a `DocumentListener` , this documentListener will listen textarea model (Document) and when some is writing you could write to the textarea2 ;)

Comment: Turns out the resulttextarea was pretty easy to fix: String filetext = new Scanner(result2, **"UTF-8"**).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
            resulttextarea.setText(filetext);

Comment: @JediGrunge great you find out yourself! That is the best practice

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with an analogous problem for so long I won't say. The following construct works fine *INSIDE* NetBeans 8.01  with jdk 8

```
String reconstituted;
//...
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
InputStream reconstitutedStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(reconstituted.getBytes(charset));
InputStreamReader ipsr = new InputStreamReader(reconstitutedStream);
```

But fails to display correct characters outside of ASCII range when run from jar file.
 Specifying the charset to the InputStreamReader constructor (like answer above, duh!! ) works both inside and outside NetBeans.

```
String reconstituted;
//...
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
InputStream reconstitutedStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(reconstituted.getBytes()); 
InputStreamReader ipsr = new InputStreamReader(reconstitutedStream, charset);
```